# Почему не ставится пакет с packagist.org?

Tags: php, yii2, github, composer, packagist

Пытаюсь поставить этот пакет 
https://packagist.org/packages/tsum/yii2-multiparser#dev-master или github
https://github.com/tsurkanovm/yii-multiparser
 вот такой командой в строке:

```
php composer.phar require "tsurkanovm/yii-multiparser"
```

Выдает такое ответ :

```
Could not find package tsurkanovm/yii-multiparser at any version for your minimum-stability (dev). Check the package spelling or your minimum-stability
```

почему если в composer.json стоит minimum-stability "dev" такоей же как у проекта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так? `php composer.phar require "tsurkanovm/yii-multiparser:dev-master"`

Answer (score 0):

У этого пакета нет ни одного теги или релиза, возможно, дело в этом.
Попробуйте установить так: `php composer.phar require "tsurkanovm/yii-multiparser@dev"`

Comment: нет не получилось но с пакагиста 20 раз скачан